# Using a Generic to return correct class extracted from a Type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to load objects encoded by JSON from a file..

I could just write the code inline each time but I wanted to move the save/load to a static utility class but I dont want to have to blindly cast to the object back in the main code.

So I currently have

```
    public Class MyClass(){

    private List<Door> doors;
    private final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Door>>(){}.getType();


    private void load(){
            Gson gsondecoder = new Gson();
            File parent = new File ("saves");
            File file =  new File(parent,"doors.json");
            List<Door> doors= null;
            if (!parent.exists())return;
            if(!file.exists())return;
            try {
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                InputStreamReader inread = new InputStreamReader(in);
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(inread);
                doors = gsondecoder.fromJson(reader,type);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

So I would like to move to a structure more like
 public Class MyClass(){

```
    private List<Door> doors;
    private final Type type = new TypeToken<List<Door>>(){}.getType();


    private void load(){
            File parent = new File ("saves");
            File file =  new File(parent,"doors.json");
            List<Door> doors= null;
            doors = (List<door>) Utility.load(file,type);
    }
```

My question is about how I can return the correct class without casting blindly 
ie just

```
door = Utility.load(file,type)
```

My idea was

```
public class Utilities {

static Gson gsonencoder = new Gson();
/**
 * The objects class must much the TypeTokens underlying class.
 *
 * @param file
 * @param object
 * @param type
 */
public static void saveFile(File file, T object, TypeToken<T> type) {
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        String encoded = gsonencoder.toJson(object, type.getType());
        out.write(encoded.getBytes());
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static T loadFile(File file, TypeToken<T> type){
    if(!file.exists())return null;
    T object = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inread = new InputStreamReader(in);
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(inread);
        object = gsonencoder.fromJson(reader,type.getType());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;

}}
```

but I am clearly missing here how generics should be used correctly.

Comment: Additionally...the downvoter....who cant even be bothered commenting on why he downvoted...nice job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the generic type (<T>). Change loadFile signature to:

```
public static <T> T loadFile(File file, TypeToken<T> type)
```

@see [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: Thanks works as Expected now ...I didnt understand the difference between a definition and a return type.. or atleast understand how they are declared seperately in a signature